# C++ input txt file using command-line but failing opening the file

Tags: c++, command-line

I'm trying to open a txt file using command line argument. 
It keeps failing opening the file..

I've read all answers on the internet and my code is exactly the same as the ones suppose to work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdbool>

using namespace ::std;
using std::printf;
using std::string;
using std::getline;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    fstream infile (argv[1]);

    if (infile.is_open() && infile.good()){
        string line="";
        while (getline(infile,line)){

            cout << line << endl;

        }
    }else{
        cout << "Failed to open file.. ";
    }


    return 0;

}
```

and I've been doing this
`g++ main.cpp -o newtest1` 
`./newtest1 < input.txt > output.txt`

it just don't seem to read `input.txt` but it's writing on `output.txt` without any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices

1) redirect the input file to standard input

2) open the input file directly

Your problem is that you are doing both simultaneously

Either do this

1) `./newtest1 < input.txt`

```
   string line="";
   while (getline(cin,line)){ // read from standard input
```

or this

2) `./newtest1 input.txt`

```
fstream infile (argv[1]);
if (infile.is_open() && infile.good()){
    string line="";
    while (getline(infile,line)){ // read from opened file
```

PS option 1 is generally considered more flexible. So unless you have a good reason to force the user to use a named file it's probably the best option.